Is this function convex over a set?
Well, I got a doubt: is this function
$$f(x, y, z) = 2xy + yz$$
Convex over the set
$$V =\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb\{R\}^3:\ x+y+2z \leq 1, x\geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0\}$$
?
Being it a quadratic form, I wrote the associated matrix
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thought its determinant is zero, and its eigenvalues are: a positive one, a negative one and a zero one.
Since the associated matrix does not depend on intervals or points, it shouldn’t be convex even on V, or instead I’m wrong but how I see it’s convex in case?

$f|V$ is not convex. For $\lambda \in [0,1]$ it is $(1-\lambda, \lambda, 0) \in V$. The function $g(\lambda) = f(1-\lambda, \lambda, 0) = 2(1-\lambda)\lambda = -2\lambda^2 +2\lambda$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is not convex.

Yes, $f$ is not convex. But is it convex on $V$?

Ah ok, I just read... You took a point on $V$ and prove it violates the definition, right? Although, it doesn't look like the definition of convexity. Just $f$ over a point...

Well, the segment ${(1-\lambda,\lambda,0): \lambda \in [0,1])}$ lies in $V$.

Definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition

But how can $f$ assume negative values on that segment, if all the variables are strictly positive?

$g$ is non-negative, for $\lambda$ is only in $[0,1]$.
